# Swift UITest cannot access presented viewController's views-buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, xcuitest, uitest

When my viewController comes with segue and presented I can not access buttons inside that viewController. Printed all elements in XCUIApplication there is no buttons with my button identifier.

```
    self.view1Button.isAccessibilityElement = true
    self.view1Button.accessibilityIdentifier = "createHomeGroupButton"
```

I give identifiers and make it accessible also its make accessible view1Button.superview. 
But I can access the presented viewControllers.view with identifier but can not access through the buttons-labels-views etc.

Edit: Also UITest Record can not access the buttons

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> I give identifiers and make it accessible also its make accessible view1Button.superview.

If you make the superview of the button accessible, you will not be able to see the button itself as part of the accessibility tree. The button needs to be the first and only accsssible element in its view hierarchy, so make sure all container views have `isAccessibilityElement` set to `false`.

The first accessible element in the tree will obscure any other accessible elements that it contains.

Answer (score 0):

If for some reason the object is not immediately present you might need to wait with timeout. You can check out the Apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/2879412-waitforexistence

```
let button = app.buttons["createHomeGroupButton"]
let buttonExists = button.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)
XCTAssert(buttonExists)
```

Comment: After 10 seconds still there isnot exist

Comment: Do you actually see that button on screen when the test is running?

Comment: Yes, there is. Also I can check its frame etc. with Sherlock app.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking  for `app.buttons["createHomeGroupButton"]` with timeout `button.waitForExistence(timeout: 10)` ?

Comment: Yes.I'm sure. I think something blocking to access buttons but I cannot find it.